# OpenWRT - change default route manually to go through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openwrt

This problem has stumped me.

I've got wireguard set up from site to site: traffic flows as expected.  I've bonded LANs and the OpenWRT devices are internet gateways.

I want to be able to use the second OpenWRT device as the gateway for the first device.

This works well when I add

```
list allowed_ips '0.0.0.0/0'
```

to the /etc/config/network script under the

```
config wireguard_wg0
```

section, and then run

```
/etc/init.d/firewall restart
```

However: I am trying to trigger this via an mwan3 script - and if I restart the network - it triggers another mwan3 replug event - and then recursion kicks in and things don't end well.

So - I tried to do this manually

```
ip route del default
ip route add default dev wg0 proto static scope link
```

I copied the routes from the working config and then tried to apply this manually.

And all I get is

```
#ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No error information
```

restarting the firewall doesn't help.

If I dump the route tables, and iptables

```
ip route show table all
iptables-save
```

I get the same configuration (this is verified with WinMerge)

but there is a difference - "auto" config works (via config and /etc/init.d/network restart) and "manual" config (via ip route ...) doesn't.

I'm stumped. Has anyone got any where I should be poking next?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay - this was an 'inverse' problem.

The issue was wireguard wasn't accepting 0.0.0.0/0 destined packets. And I couldn't find a way of configuring it on the fly to add routes to a particular interface.

So if the 0.0.0.0/0 route is added by default to the wg0, and then not used by default.

When the default traffic is not required to flow over wg0 interface the default route is set to the locate device - this then works.  When switching to the backup interface (over wg), just re-enable the default routing to the wg0 interface, which it is already accepting 'default' traffic.

Voila! It works.

Oh - and restart the firewall, so forwarded traffic flows as well.

Comment: Can you add the commands/configs you used? I am trying to learn to put my whole network behind a VPN - and this seems to be pretty close to that :) Thanks!